# get path of file/directory using only read() and open() system calls and loop through all files in directory and sub-directories

Tags: c, file, operating-system, directory, system-calls

I'm trying to give my program a directory path and loop through all the files in this directory and and the files in the sub-directories to find only the c files and compile them.
I don't want to use readdir\opendir to do so.
I was able to open the directory using the:

```
(fd = open(".", O_DIRECTORY | O_RDONLY))
```

now in order to access the files in the directory and its sub directories I want to use the read() system call. but how can I do it?
when I want to read a file i do it like this:

```
char c;
read(fd1, &c, 1) == 1)
```

but I guess that using a char isn't the right way to go..so what should I use instead?

and last thing:
in order to access the files in the sub-directories(while I will use recursion to do so) I have to be able to define if I'm reading a file of a sub-directory, I know that the is_dir macro can do this but in this case I can't use it,so what is the right way the check if it's a file or a directory?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: And why don't you want to use `readdir`/`opendir`?! They **are** ***the*** correct thing to use here.

Comment: @Antti Haapala  this is a part of a much bigger learning challenge project my teacher gave us to do on out free time, the point of it is to only use the open() and write() system calls. we were also not allowed to use  fopen to heandle files...I know how to do it using the readdir/opendir ,but I'm trying not to(although I know that in real life I would use it if I ever need to do something similar)

Comment: If you only can `read` directories, then you need to learn how they are stored on disk and what the contents of a "directory" is when you read it. And note that it's not portable, maybe not even between disks on the same computer (as it depends on the filesystem used).

Comment: Most systems simply do not support/permit `read` on directories. It's a legacy thing some BSDs still have. What you've been asked to do does not make sense.